# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting in tkinter

Tags: python, typeerror

The program is meant to work out the price of adult tickets and child tickets and show them to the user. This is just a little test im doing but I keep getting an error. I've read show to fix it but it hasn't worked for me.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
import pickle
def calculateprice():
    adult_tickets=str(adult_t.get())
    child_tickets=str(child_t.get())

    adult=adult_tickets*120
    child=child_tickets*60
    results=Label(mgui, text="adult cost"% adult).grid(row=7, column=2)
    result_child(mgui, text="child cost"% child).grid(row=8, column=2)
    return
mgui =Tk()
mgui.geometry("400x200+200+200")
mgui.title("ticket")

adult_t=StringVar()
child_t=StringVar()

label1=Label(mgui,text="Welcome", fg="red").grid(row=0,column=2)
label2=Label(mgui,text="adult").grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)
label3=Label(mgui,text="child").grid(row=2,column=1, sticky=W)

adult_tickets1=Entry(mgui,textvariable=adult_t).grid(row=1,column=2)
child_tickets2=Entry(mgui,textvariable=child_t).grid(row=2,column=2)

button1=Button(mgui, text="Calculate",command=calculateprice).grid(row=3,column=0)

mgui.mainloop()
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pyhton\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
results=Label(mgui, text="adult cost"% adult).grid(row=7, column=2)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: I think `"adult cost "+str(adult)` is what you want.  Or `"adult cost %s" % adult`.  Also `adult_tickets=str(adult_t.get())` should be `adult_tickets=int(adult_t.get())`.  Similar to `child_tickets`.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code just replace `calculateprice()`

```
def calculateprice():
    adult_tickets=int(adult_t.get())
    child_tickets=int(child_t.get())

    adult=adult_tickets*120
    child=child_tickets*60
    results=Label(mgui, text="adult cost {0}".format(adult)).grid(row=7, column=2)
    result_child = Label(mgui, text="child cost {0}".format(child)).grid(row=8, column=2)
    # return
```

This is an example to give some guidence, it's the same but inhereting the `class`

```
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):

    @staticmethod
    def show_total(amaunt):
        messagebox.showinfo('Total', '{0}$'.format(amaunt))


    def calculateprice(self):
        adult = self.adult_var.get() * 120
        child = self.child_var.get() * 60

        self.aduld_label.config(text="adult cost {0}".format(adult))
        self.child_label.config(text="child cost {0}".format(child))

        self.show_total(adult + child)

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Ticket")        
        self.geometry('400x200+200+200')

        # the reference is required if is needed access again or use a 
        # placement method in a diferent moment

        self.adult_var = tk.IntVar()
        self.child_var = tk.IntVar()

        # these items are showing but they are empty, wuitch is 
        # kinda equivalent to not drawind them on screen
        self.aduld_label = tk.Label(self)
        self.aduld_label.grid(row=7, column=2)
        self.child_label = tk.Label(self)
        self.child_label.grid(row=8, column=2)


        # no need to store as variable in this example
        tk.Label(self, text="Welcome", fg="red").grid(row=0, column=2)
        tk.Label(self, text="Adult").grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Label(self, text="Child").grid(row=2,column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.adult_var).grid(row=1, column=2)
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.child_var).grid(row=2, column=2)

        tk.Button(self, text="Calculate", command=self.calculateprice).grid(row=3, column=0)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Main()
    app.mainloop()
```